# Clear a ComboBox after Search in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have research by criteria with Two combobox, it works fine.
I have a button Display All : to clear the Combobox and the DataGrid display again all elements.

The problem is : the Combobox must be empty when I click on the Button Dispaly All, The first two tests are correct ( the Combobox are empty..and the Datagrid display all the elements), after that...I have the list of two Combobox are Empty!!

1) Without select an element in Combobox(just dispaly the datagrid):I have 6 elements in the datagrid, it is correct..and the combobox are Empty :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81xgF.png)

2)
After select the Search criteria (select two elements in the Combobox), I have the result correct: (Exemple: I have just 3 results, it is the correct action)

3) 
When I click on the button Display All (after two tests correct ):the list in the Combobox are Empty!! :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJokz.png)

XAML:

```
   <Window x:Class="WPFAuthentification.Views.BusinesseventsView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" >   

     <Label Content="Entity Type" />
     <ComboBox Name="comboCodeType"
     ItemsSource="{Binding EntityLevelEnum}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding EntityType, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, TargetNullValue=''}"
     />

     <Label Content="Criticality" />
     <ComboBox Name="comboType" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding LevelCriticalityEnum}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding Criticality, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, TargetNullValue=''}" />



    <Button Content="Dislplay all" ToolTip="Display All Business Events" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"  Command="{Binding Initialize}"  />

     <DataGrid Name="businesseventsalarms" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding BusinessEventsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBusinessevent}" ... >
    </Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public BusinesseventsViewModel()
    {
        businessEventsList = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass>(WCFclient.getAllBusinessEvent());
        levelCriticalityEnum = new ObservableCollection<Level_Criticality>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Level_Criticality)).Cast<Level_Criticality>());
        entityLevelEnum = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEntityLevel>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(BusinessEntityLevel)).Cast<BusinessEntityLevel>());

        //Function of Button Display All
        initialize = new RelayCommand<string>(initFunc);    
   }        
    private void initFunc(object obj)
    {
        entityLevelEnum.Clear();          
        levelCriticalityEnum.Clear();          
        OnPropertyChanged("EntityLevelEnum");
        OnPropertyChanged("LevelCriticalityEnum");     
    }   

    private string  entityType;
    public string EntityType
    {
        get { return entityType; }
        set
        {
            entityType = value;
            businessEventsList = filterByCriteria(entityType, criticality);
            OnPropertyChanged("BusinessEventsList");      
            OnPropertyChanged("EntityType");


        }
    }     
    private string criticality;
    public string Criticality
    {
        get { return criticality; }
        set
        {
            criticality = value;
            businessEventsList = filterByCriteria(entityType, criticality);
            OnPropertyChanged("BusinessEventsList");
            OnPropertyChanged("Criticality");                
        }
    }  

     public ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass> filterByCriteria(string entityType, string criticality)
    {

        BusinessEventsList = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass>(WCFclient.getAllBusinessEvent());     

        ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass> updatedList = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass>();


        if ((entityType != null && entityType != "") && (Criticality != null))
            {
                updatedList = new ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass>(BusinessEventsList.Where(a => a.EntityType.ToString().ToLower().Equals(criticality)
                                                                         && a.Critciality.ToString().Equals(criticality));
            }

                return updatedList;                    
          }  

    } 

        //List of all BusinessEvents 
    public ObservableCollection<BusinessEventClass> BusinessEventsList
    {
        get { return businessEventsList; }
        set
        {
            businessEventsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BusinessEventsList");
        }
    }

    //List of LevelCriticalityEnum
    private ObservableCollection<Level_Criticality> levelCriticalityEnum;
    public ObservableCollection<Level_Criticality> LevelCriticalityEnum
    {
        get { return levelCriticalityEnum; }
        set
        {
            levelCriticalityEnum = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TypeEnum");
        }
    }

    //List of EntityLevelEnum
    private ObservableCollection<BusinessEntityLevel> entityLevelEnum;
    public ObservableCollection<BusinessEntityLevel> EntityLevelEnum
    {
        get { return entityLevelEnum; }
        set
        {
            entityLevelEnum = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TypeEnum");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: modify the code in code behind

```
private void DisplayAll_Clickk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {   //comboCodeType : name of combobox for the EntityType
        comboCodeType.SelectedIndex = -1;
         //comboType: name of combobox for the Criticality
        comboType.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

It works fine